# How to use pyramid.response.FileIter

Tags: python, pyramid

I have the following view code that attempts to "stream" a zipfile to the client for download:

```
import os
import zipfile
import tempfile
from pyramid.response import FileIter

def zipper(request):
    _temp_path = request.registry.settings['_temp']
    tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', dir=_temp_path, delete=True)

    tmpfile_path = tmpfile.name

    ## creating zipfile and adding files
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(tmpfile_path, "w")
    z.write('somefile1.txt')
    z.write('somefile2.txt')
    z.close()

    ## renaming the zipfile
    new_zip_path = _temp_path + '/somefilegroup.zip'
    os.rename(tmpfile_path, new_zip_path)

    ## re-opening the zipfile with new name
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(new_zip_path, 'r')
    response = FileIter(z.fp)

    return response
```

However, this is the Response I get in the browser:

**`Could not convert return value of the view callable function newsite.static.zipper into a response object. The value returned was .`**

I suppose I am not using FileIter correctly.

---

## UPDATE:

Since updating with Michael Merickel's suggestions, the FileIter function is working correctly. However, still lingering is a MIME type error that appears on the client (browser):
`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip: "http://newsite.local:6543/zipper?data=%7B%22ids%22%3A%5B6%2C7%5D%7D"`

To better illustrate the issue, I have included a tiny `.py` and `.pt` file on Github: **https://github.com/thapar/zipper-fix**

Answer (score 9):

`FileIter` is not a response object, just like your error message says. It is an iterable that can be used for the response body, that's it. Also the `ZipFile` can accept a file object, which is more useful here than a file path. Let's try writing into the `tmpfile`, then rewinding that file pointer back to the start, and using it to write out without doing any fancy renaming.

```
import os
import zipfile
import tempfile
from pyramid.response import FileIter

def zipper(request):
    _temp_path = request.registry.settings['_temp']
    fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w+b', dir=_temp_path, delete=True)

    ## creating zipfile and adding files
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(fp, "w")
    z.write('somefile1.txt')
    z.write('somefile2.txt')
    z.close()

    # rewind fp back to start of the file
    fp.seek(0)

    response = request.response
    response.content_type = 'application/zip'
    response.app_iter = FileIter(fp)
    return response
```

I changed the mode on `NamedTemporaryFile` to `'w+b'` as per the docs to allow the file to be written to **and** read from.

Comment: If you want to change the name of the file when it's downloaded, just set the content-disposition header: `response.content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="somefilegroup.zip"`.

Comment: In my client, I am still receiving this error: `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip: "http://newsite.local:6543/zipper?data=%7B%22fileids%22%3A%5B6%2C7%5D%7D'".` This is the same error I receive when I use `FileResponse`. I opted for `FileIter` because I was under the impression that I would not receive the MIME type error.

Comment: Not enough to go on here, but it sounds like you didn't set the content-disposition header.

Comment: I updated the question with this tiny project to demonstrate the MIME type issue: https://github.com/thapar/zipper-fix

Comment: I tested your project on chrome/firefox/safari on my mac and everything behaved completely normally. On a side note, please don't hijack your question and change the discussion. The original question about the FileIter is answered and this other stuff should be a new issue. StackOverflow's QA format really isn't conducive to what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

current Pyramid version has 2 convenience classes for this use case- FileResponse, FileIter. The snippet below will serve a static file. I ran this code - the downloaded file is named "download" like the view name. To change the file name and more set the Content-Disposition header or have a look at the arguments of pyramid.response.Response.

```
from pyramid.response import FileResponse

@view_config(name="download")
def zipper(request):    
    path = 'path_to_file'
    return FileResponse(path, request) #passing request is required
```

docs:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/response.html#

hint: extract the Zip logic from the view if possible

Comment: Sascha, I'm aware of `FileResponse` and how to use it. My question is regarding `FileIter`.

Comment: now got your point that you already use pyramid.response.FileIter - your code misses the import statement. However FileIter is used within implementation of FileResponse. Look at the source code. If this fits not your use case, plaese explain why.

Comment: I have already looked at the source code. The point is I am not using it correctly. I posted on here to see if my code could be corrected by someone that is familiar with the flow and syntax.

Comment: excerpt from docs: A view callable’s ultimate responsibility is to create a Pyramid Response object. This can be done by creating a Response object in the view callable code and returning it directly

You did not return a response object. This is what you are doing wrong. By using FileResponse are response object is created, you return a bare FileIter object.